# Why do tendons become less flexible with age?

Tags: tendons, aging

This [page from the Mayo Foundation for Medical Education and Research](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/tendinitis/expert-answers/tendinitis/faq-20057872) says:

> Your tendons become less flexible with age, so tendinitis is more common as you get older.

Why do tendons become less flexible with age?

Answer (score 4):

As you grow older, your tendons become more rigid and brittle. This is probably because of decrease in the water content of tendons, which is one of the reasons why tendons are flexible. This decrease in water content makes your tendons stiffer and weaker. They also become less tolerable of stress. This causes you to be more prone to tendon injuries, which can then lead to tendinitis.

---

<sup>[Effects of Aging](http://orthoinfo.aaos.org/topic.cfm?topic=A00191)</sup>

<sup>[Effects of Aging on the Musculoskeletal System](http://www.merckmanuals.com/home/bone_joint_and_muscle_disorders/biology_of_the_musculoskeletal_system/effects_of_aging_on_the_musculoskeletal_system.html)</sup>